# Converting Roman Numerals to integers in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is now my current code after what user2486 said.

```
def romanMap():
    map=(("M",  1000),("CM", 900),("D",  500),("CD", 400),("C",  100),("XC", 90),("L",  50),("XL", 40),("X",  10),("IX", 9),("V",  5),("V", 4),("I",  1))
    return map
firstNum=ns([0])
secondNum=ns([1])
def main():
    ns=str(input("Enter a roman numeral"))
    total=0
    result=0
    while ns:
        firstNum=(romanMap(ns[0]))
         secondNum=(romanMap(ns[1]) 
        if firstNum is len(ns)>1 or secondNum-1:
                        total=total+firstNum
            ns=ns[1:]
        else:
                        total=total+ns[1]-ns[0]
            ns=ns[2:]
      print (total)
main()
```

I am getting this error with     while ns:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'ns' referenced before assignment

Comment: Thats the tedious and harder way to do it, it would be more fficient if you used a dictionary. For reference take a look at an already written functionality to do that, http://svn.python.org/projects/python/branches/pep-0384/Doc/tools/roman.py

Comment: I... can't imagine those functions are doing what you want them to do.

Comment: @roippi -- of course not.  If they were, OP might not be here asking a question :)

Comment: @mgilson well yeah, but he just goes on to say that his program doesn't work.  If I have a bunch of bricks made out of mashed potatoes and try to build a house out of them, I don't say "my house doesn't work."

Comment: @roippi no, you start a kickstarter about making houses out of recycled potatoes and use the money to solve your problem.

Comment: Please don't change a question so drastically - create a new question instead! Anyway, an "UnboundLocalError" means that a variable has not been assigned to and it has been attempted to be used! In this case, it's missing the assignment to `ns` from the user input. Also note 1) that `ns[1]` might throw an exception if `len(ns) == 1`; 2) the initial assignments outside the loop to `firstNum/secondNum` do nothing; 3) the total should only be computed *from* `firstNum/secondNum` as `ns[x]` returns a string; 4) implement a function called `numberOfNumeral` that does what I suggested, and use it ;)

Comment: To add to @enginefree, the roman module birth is described in Dive Into Python 3 -- see http://stackoverflow.com/a/19313140/1346705 for links.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider this additional pseudo-code and hints (some of it is valid Python, some isn't, but there be notes).

```
def numberOfNumeral(n):
    """ Return the number represented by the single numeral """
    # e.g. "v" -> 5, "i" -> 5 (and handle v/V cases, etc.)

# avoid "string" as a variable name
# I chose "ns" for "numerals" (which might be better),
# but I'm also a bit terse .. anyway, name variables for what they represents.
ns = str(input("Enter a roman numeral"))

while ns:
   firstNum = numberOfNumeral(ns[0])
   # This makes secondValue = -1 when there is only one numeral left
   # so firstNum is always "at least" secondNum when len(ns) == 1. 
   secondNum = numberOfNumeral(ns[1]) if len(ns) > 1 else -1
   if firstNum is at least secondNum:
      # Add firstNum to total.
      # Remove the character - so that the loop state advances.
      # If we don't don't his, as in the original, it will never end.
      # Here we use "slice notation".
      ns = ns[1:] 
   else:
      # Add the difference, secondNum - firstNum, to total.
      # Remove both characters - again, so we advance state.
      ns = ns[2:]
```

- [Explain Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/pythons-slice-notation)
- [Does Python have a ternary conditional operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/ternary-conditional-operator-in-python)

Comment: Wait, why are you starting at `ns[1]` instead of `ns[0]`? Other than that, this is a nice skeleton for the user to work from.

Comment: Do i Need to define firstNum/secondNum?

Comment: @Jake: There's no separate "declaring" and "defining" in Python—just assign a value to a variable.

Comment: well I mean firstNum=ns([0]) secondNum=ns([1])

Comment: @Jake: you already give them values at the top of the loop. Giving them different values before that isn't going to help anything.

Answer (score 33):

No need to reinvent the wheel (unless you want to). Python once came with a converter (so you can go to the [Python 3.4.1 source code](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-341/) and grab the module at this location: `/Python-3.4.1/Doc/tools/roman.py`; or perhaps install it with pip as someone in the comments said here; I haven't verified the pip version; anyway, then you can do):

```
import roman;
n=roman.fromRoman("X"); #n becomes 10
```

If you need it for numbers 5000 and above, you'll need to write a new function, though, and maybe make your own font to represent the lines over the roman numerals. (It will only work with some numbers, at that. Stopping at 4999 is a really good idea.)

To convert to roman numerals, use `roman.toRoman(myInt)`.

Alternatively (for converting to Roman numerals only), you can do this in Python 3.9.2 (which I only partially understand due to a lack of documentation; so, all my arguments probably aren't right; but, it seems to work; formatter is depreciated anyway; so, don't expect it to stay around a long time):

```
import formatter
a=formatter.AbstractFormatter("I don't know what I'm supposed to put here, but it doesn't seem to matter for our purposes.")
roman_numeral=a.format_roman(case="I", counter=5) #Case doesn't seem to matter, either.
#roman_numeral now equals "V"
```

Someone else actually linked to the same source code the roman module uses in one of the comments above, but I don't believe they mentioned that it actually comes with Python. It doesn't seem to come with Python anymore, but it did in version 3.4.1.

Comment: I don't think it comes included with Python, but if you have pip it can be installed with `pip install roman`

Comment: Or `easy_install roman`, since that actually comes with python.

Comment: Case should be `'I'` if you want upper case

Comment: Direct link to [roman.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.4.2/Doc/tools/roman.py) included with Python 3.4.2.

Answer (score 11):

Roman numerals are read from left to right, as you add or subtract the value of each symbol.

If a value is lower than the following value, it will be subtracted. Otherwise it will be added.

For example, we want to conver the Roman numeral MCMLIV to an Arabic number:

```
M = 1000 must be added, because the following letter C =100 is lower.
C = 100 must be subtracted because the following letter M =1000 is greater.
M = 1000 must be added, because the following letter L = 50 is lower.
L = 50 must be added, because the following letter I =1 is lower.
I = 1 must be subtracted, because the following letter V = 5 is greater.
V = 5 must be added, because there are no more symbols left.
```

We can now calculate the number:

```
1000 - 100 + 1000 + 50 - 1 + 5 = 1954
```

ref : http://www.mathinary.com/roman_numerals_from_roman_numerals_to_arabic_numbers.jsp

```
def from_roman(num):
    roman_numerals = {'I':1, 'V':5, 'X':10, 'L':50, 'C':100, 'D':500, 'M':1000}
    result = 0
    for i,c in enumerate(num):
        if (i+1) == len(num) or roman_numerals[c] >= roman_numerals[num[i+1]]:
            result += roman_numerals[c]
        else:
            result -= roman_numerals[c]
    return result
```

Comment: Does not work for 'II', 'III', 'VII', and etc (gives 0, -1, and 5 in the case)

Comment: Fixed it. Lacked an equal sign where it does the first comparison

Answer (score 6):

A nice compact version with no external libraries:

```
def rn_to_int(s):
  d = {'m': 1000, 'd': 500, 'c': 100, 'l': 50, 'x': 10, 'v': 5, 'i': 1}
  n = [d[i] for i in s.lower() if i in d]
  return sum([i if i>=n[min(j+1, len(n)-1)] else -i for j,i in enumerate(n)])


for numeral, expected in [['CLXIV', 164], ['MDCCLXXXIII', 1783], ['xiv', 14]]:
  assert rn_to_int(numeral) == expected
```

Comment: Any idea how to fix that?
`Index
1      0
2      0
3      0
4      0
5      0
      ..
65    II
66    II
67    II
68    II
69    II
Name: 0, Length: 69, dtype: object
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\pandas\data.py", line 115, in <module>
    rn_to_int(xAs)
  File "C:\pandas\data.py", line 111, in rn_to_int
    n = [d[i] for i in s.lower() if i in d]
  File "C:\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 5902, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'lower'`

Comment: looks like you're tryint to use the `rn_to_int` function on a pandas series. You should run it on a string

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I have a dataframe with nans converted to 0s and getting this one: https://onecompiler.com/python/3zhu254qe Any suggestions to modify to ignore zeros? thanks so much.

Comment: For now this seems a working fix: https://onecompiler.com/python/3zhtzvyeu from this ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69279029/10789707

Comment: Amazing! It worked very well as expected! Thank again. Be well!

Answer (score 4):

Right-to-left solution that is a bit more Pythonic (no indexes) and relatively short.

Algorithm:

- Reverse the roman numeral and map it to a list of numbers
- Figure out which numbers should be subtracted and then sum the list

Example:

`'xiv'` => `sum(5, -1, 10)` => `14`

```
def parse_roman(s):
    numerals = {'M':1000, 'D':500, 'C':100, 'L':50, 'X':10, 'V':5, 'I':1}
    n = 0
    last_value = 0
    # e.g. convert 'xiv' to (5, 1, 10)
    for value in (numerals[c] for c in reversed(s.upper())):
        # debugging
        v = (value, -value)[value < last_value]
        print('{:6} += {:5}  <== cur, prev = {}, {}'.format(n, v, value, last_value))
        # subtract smaller values that come after larger ones, otherwise add
        n += (value, -value)[value < last_value]
        last_value = value
    return n
```

Output:

```
parse_roman('MMCMXCVIII')
     0 +=     1  <== cur, prev = 1, 0
     1 +=     1  <== cur, prev = 1, 1
     2 +=     1  <== cur, prev = 1, 1
     3 +=     5  <== cur, prev = 5, 1
     8 +=   100  <== cur, prev = 100, 5
   108 +=   -10  <== cur, prev = 10, 100
    98 +=  1000  <== cur, prev = 1000, 10
  1098 +=  -100  <== cur, prev = 100, 1000
   998 +=  1000  <== cur, prev = 1000, 100
  1998 +=  1000  <== cur, prev = 1000, 1000
2998
```

Note: It would be nice to find a (short, inline) method for changing the signs of the sequence on the fly. For example, `(5, 1, 10)` ==> `(5, -1, 10)`.

---

**Update:** This is as close as I got before giving up. It's identical to the code above, but it uses `itertools.tee()` with `zip()` to generate pairs of the previous and current values to eliminate the need for the state variables. The single call to `next(cur)` makes that list one shorter than `prev` which is all the state we need to figure out whether to add or subtract the current value.

Example:

```
cur, prev = (5, 1, 10), (5, 1, 10)
# Take one from cur and zip the rest
next(cur) + sum(... zip(cur, prev))
# 5 + ... zip( (1, 10), (5, 1, 10) )  ==>  5 + ... ((1, 5), (10, 1))
```

Code:

```
from itertools import tee

def parse_roman(s):
    numerals = {'M':1000, 'D':500, 'C':100, 'L':50, 'X':10, 'V':5, 'I':1}
    cur, prev = tee(numerals[c] for c in reversed(s.upper()))
    return next(cur) + sum((cur, -cur)[cur < prev] for cur, prev in zip(cur,prev))
```

Answer (score 3):

Okay, there are a lot of things wrong with what you currently have.

First, the reason you are getting a bunch of 0's is because you are never exiting your `while string != "":` loop, and it isn't ever adding integers to the total.  So `total` remains zero, and keeps getting printed.  I've commented the code you posted to help you understand what is going on.

```
def main():
    string=str(input("Enter a roman numeral"))
    total=0
    while string != "": # Empty strings evaluate as False, this can just be 'while string:'
        if string[1] == string[2] or string == len([1]): # Here you are testing the 2nd and 3rd elements.
                                                         # Also, you want to do len(string) == 1
                                                         # string will never == len([1]), so you never
                                                         # execute the code in this block.
            total += string[1]+1   # You want to add the corresponding value of string[0], use a dictionary.
        print (total)

        # Missing the else statement in the pseudocode.
main()
```

user2864740 has some good comments in their posted solution, look over that to see some of the things you were doing wrong.

Here is Python (2.7 unfortunately) code that does what your given pseudocode says.

```
val = {'I': 1, 'V': 5, 'X': 10, 'L': 50, 'C': 100, 'D': 500, 'M': 1000}

def main():
    string = str(raw_input('Enter a roman numeral: '))
    string = string.upper()
    total = 0
    while string:
        if len(string) == 1 or val[string[0]] >= val[string[1]]:
            total += val[string[0]]
            string = string[1:]
        else:
            total += val[string[1]] - val[string[0]]
            string = string[2:]
    print total

main()
```

Please note that the pseudocode you posted is NOT correct.  Note what it will do for the input `'IIV'`.  It will subtract 1 from 1, then add 5.  But what it should do is subtract 2 from 5.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my solution:

```
numerals = [
        {'letter': 'M', 'value': 1000},
        {'letter': 'D', 'value': 500},
        {'letter': 'C', 'value': 100},
        {'letter': 'L', 'value': 50},
        {'letter': 'X', 'value': 10},
        {'letter': 'V', 'value': 5},
        {'letter': 'I', 'value': 1},
    ]

def arabic_to_roman(number):
    remainder = number
    result = ''
    for numeral_index in xrange(len(numerals)):
        numeral = numerals[numeral_index]
        next_numeral = numerals[numeral_index + 1] if numeral_index + 1 < len(numerals) else None

        factor = remainder / numeral['value']
        remainder -= factor * numeral['value']

        if next_numeral:
            numeral_difference = numeral['value'] - next_numeral['value']
            if (remainder - numeral_difference >= 0) and (numeral_difference > next_numeral['value']):
                result += next_numeral['letter'] + numeral['letter']
                remainder -= numeral_difference

        if factor > 0:
            result += numeral['letter'] * factor

    return result


def roman_to_arabic(number):
    index_by_letter = {}
    for index in xrange(len(numerals)):
        index_by_letter[numerals[index]['letter']] = index

    result = 0
    previous_value = None
    for letter in reversed(number):
        index = index_by_letter[letter]
        value = numerals[index]['value']
        if (previous_value is None) or (previous_value <= value):
            result += value
        else:
            result -= value
        previous_value = value

    return result
```

Comment: roman_to_arabic might be wrong, on input = XIV, it gives 16, when it is supposed to be 14.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post, but I would like to add 3 solutions to convert roman numerals to numbers.

**Solution 1: (Approx Runtime = 52ms)**

```
def romanToInt(self, s: str) -> int:

     roman = {'I':1, 'V':5, 'X':10, 'L':50, 'C':100, 'D':500, 'M':1000 }    
     num = 0

     for i in range(len(s)):

        if i!= len(s)-1 and roman[s[i]] < roman[s[i+1]]:
             num += roman[s[i]]*-1
        else:
             num += roman[s[i]]

      return num
```

**Solution 2: (Approx Runtime = 60ms)**

```
def romanToInt(self, s: str) -> int:

     roman = {'I':1, 'V':5, 'X':10, 'L':50, 'C':100, 'D':500, 'M':1000 }    
     num = 0

     s = s.replace("IV", "IIII").replace("IX", "VIIII")
     s = s.replace("XL", "XXXX").replace("XC", "LXXXX")
     s = s.replace("CD", "CCCC").replace("CM", "DCCCC")

     for x in s:
        num += roman[x]

     return num
```

**Solution 3: (Approx Runtime = 48ms)**

```
def romanToInt(self, s: str) -> int:

     roman = {'I':1, 'V':5, 'X':10, 'L':50, 'C':100, 'D':500, 'M':1000 }    
     num = 0

     for i in range(len(s)-1):
        if roman[s[i]] < roman[s[i+1]]:
            num += roman[s[i]]*-1
            continue

         num += roman[s[i]]

      num +=roman[s[-1]]

      return num
```

The simplest solution appears to be the best at times :)

Answer (score 1):

what about This piece of Code

```
mapping = {'I': 1, 'V': 5, 'X': 10,'L': 50, 'C': 100, 'D': 500, 'M':1000}

def roman_to_dec(roman):
"""
Convert the roman no to decimal
"""
dec = last = 0
for i in range(0, len(roman)):
    no = mapping.get(roman[i])
    # subtract last 2 times cuz one for this pass and another for last pass
    dec = dec + (no - 2 * last) if no > last else dec + no
    last = no
return dec
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Comment: It is Converting roman no to decimal...with less line of code... what more to explain..!

Answer (score 0):

There is a very detailed description of the development of the Roman numeral converters in the [Dive Into Python 3](http://getpython3.com/diveintopython3/index.html) by Mark Pilgrim. See the [5.3. Case Study: Roman Numerals](http://getpython3.com/diveintopython3/regular-expressions.html#romannumerals) that introduces the problem and details.

But that is not all. See the [Chapter 9. Unit Testing](http://getpython3.com/diveintopython3/unit-testing.html) where the analysis and the implementation of Roman numeral converters continues, including interesting optimization and exception throwing -- the (unit) test driven development.

It is directly related to the enginefree's reference to the code in the first comment below the question (the code was written by Mark Pilgrim).

Answer (score 0):

Here's something i came up with using dictionary. It should be v.simple. Tell me what you think. I must say it does not handle the spoof roman numerals written in the form of MIM (instead of MCMXCIX for 1999). This is only for valid roman numerals.

```
import re
s = 0;
a = dict();
b = dict();
r = "MMCMXCVIII"

a['CM'] = 900;
a['IX'] = 9;
a ['IV'] = 4;
a ['XL'] = 40;
a ['CD'] = 400;
a ['XC'] = 90;

b['M'] = 1000;
b['C'] = 100;
b['D'] = 500;
b['X'] = 10;
b['V'] = 5;
b['L'] = 50;
b['I'] = 1;

# Handle the tricky 4's and 9's first and remove them from the string

for key in a:
        if key in r: 
            r = re.sub(key,'',r)
            s+=a[key];
# Then straightforward multiplication of the not-so-tricky ones by their count.

for key in b:
         s+= r.count(key) * b[key];

print s; # This will print 2998
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```html
def roman_integer(roman):
    roman = roman.upper() # for taking care of upper or lower case letters
    integer_rep = 0
    roman_to_integer_map = tuple()
    roman_to_integer_map = (('M',1000),
                            ('CM',900),
                            ('D',500),
                            ('CD',400),
                            ('C',100),
                            ('XC',90),
                            ('L',50),
                            ('XL',40),
                            ('X',10),
                            ('IX',9),
                            ('V',5),
                            ('IV',4),
                            ('I',1))
    roman_numeral_pattern = re.compile("""
    ^                   # beginning of string
    M{0,4}              # thousands - 0 to 4 M's
    (CM|CD|D?C{0,3})    # hundreds - 900 (CM), 400 (CD), 0-300 (0 to 3 C's),
                        #            or 500-800 (D, followed by 0 to 3 C's)
    (XC|XL|L?X{0,3})    # tens - 90 (XC), 40 (XL), 0-30 (0 to 3 X's),
                        #        or 50-80 (L, followed by 0 to 3 X's)
    (IX|IV|V?I{0,3})    # ones - 9 (IX), 4 (IV), 0-3 (0 to 3 I's),
                        #        or 5-8 (V, followed by 0 to 3 I's)
    $                   # end of string
    """ ,re.VERBOSE)

    if not roman_numeral_pattern.search(roman):
        return 0
    index = 0
    for numeral, integer in roman_to_integer_map:
        while roman[index:index+len(numeral)] == numeral:
            #print numeral, integer, 'matched'
            integer_rep += integer
            index += len(numeral)
    return integer_rep
```

Answer (score 0):

Work from right to left of the roman numeral to add or subtract values. Easy.

```
def rome(roman_num):
     d = {'I':1,'V':5,'X':10,'L':50,'C':100,'D':500,'M':1000}
     nl = list(roman_num)
     sum = d[nl[len(nl)-1]]
     for i in range(len(nl)-1,0,-1):
             if d[nl[i]]>d[nl[i-1]]:
                     sum -= d[nl[i-1]]
             else:
                     sum += d[nl[i-1]]       
     return sum
```

Answer (score 0):

```
roman_conver=[  (1,'I'),
                (5,'V'),
                (10,'X'),
                (50,'L'),
                (100,'C'),
                (500,'D'),
                (1000,'M'),
                    ]
def romantonumeral(roman):
    tot = 0
    for i in range(0,len(roman)):
        for each in roman_conver:
            if roman[i]==each[1]:
                if each[0]>tot:
                    tot = each[0] - tot
                else:
                    tot = tot + each[0]
    return tot
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the leetcode questions.

```
def romanToInt(s):
    sum=0
    dict={'M':1000,'D':500,'C':100,'L':50,'X':10,'V':5,'I':1}

    for i in range(len(s)):
        if i==0:
            sum=sum+dict[s[i]]
        else:
            if s[i]=='M':
                sum=sum+1000
                if s[i-1]=='C':
                    sum=sum-200      

            elif s[i]=='D':
                sum=sum+500
                if s[i-1]=='C':
                    sum=sum-200

            elif s[i]=='C':
                sum=sum+100
                if s[i-1]=='X':
                    sum=sum-20

            elif s[i]=='L':
                sum=sum+50
                if s[i-1]=='X':
                    sum=sum-20

            elif s[i]=='X':
                sum=sum+10
                if s[i-1]=='I':
                    sum=sum-2

            elif s[i]=='V':
                sum=sum+5
                if s[i-1]=='I':
                    sum=sum-2
            elif s[i]=='I':
                sum=sum+1
    return (sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def romanToInt(self, s: str) -> int:
    roman_dict = {'I':1, 'V':5, 'X':10, 'L':50, 'C':100, 'D':500, 'M':1000}
    int_equ = 0

    for i in range(len(s)):
        if i > 0 and roman_dict[s[i]] > roman_dict[s[i-1]]:
            int_equ += roman_dict[s[i]] - 2*roman_dict[s[i-1]]
        else:
            int_equ += roman_dict[s[i]]

    return int_equ
```

Comment: Runtime is 48 ms.

Answer (score -3):

try this:

```
def translate(string):
    values = {"i":1, "v":5, "x":10, "l":50, "c":100, "m":1000}
    return sum(map(lambda x: values[x], string))
```

The lambda stands for a one-line function. That's why they are called **anonymous functions**. You don't have to define them outide using def and all that formality.

You can type something like this on the shell:

> > > f = lambda x: x + 3
> > >       f(3)
> > >           6
> > >           or 
> > >       f = lambda x,y: x + y
> > >       f("foo", "bar")
> > >           'foobar'

Im using **map** to apply my new-born function into every element of a iterable. In this case, the iterable is one string like "mclvii". Doing it i generated a list where each value its his rersepective value. See a lambda example to calculate squares:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4]
>>> square = lambda x: x**2
>>> l = map(square, a)
>>> l = [1,4,9,16]
```

So, it's lambda when you need a function on the fly, and map when you want to apply a function to all elements in a list.

Now a example using recursion:

```
def translate2(string):
    values = {"i":1, "v":5, "x":10, "l":50, "c":100, "m":1000}
    if not string:
        return 0
    return values[string[0]] + translate2(string[1:])
```

Comment: Using lambda functions here just makes things more complicated. If you use a listcomp instead of map, you can just use the expression directly. If you really want a function, it already exists in operator, so you don't need to recreate it.

Comment: Wrong Answer. Please delete this