# Converting roman numerals to integers

Tags: python, algorithm, roman-numerals

I've been given a task to convert roman numerals to integers and have been able to come up with the following solution:

```
def roman_numeral_to_int(string):
    symbols = {
        'I': 1,
        'V': 5,
        'X': 10,
        'L': 50,
        'C': 100,
        'D': 500,
        'M': 1000
    }
    repetitions = {}
    result = 0
    skip = 0
    for i, c in enumerate(string):
        if i == skip and i != 0:
            continue
        if c not in symbols:
            return None
        if c in repetitions.items():
            repetitions[c] += 1
        else:
            repetitions = {c: 1}
        for r, v in repetitions.items():
            if (r in ['L', 'D', 'V'] and v > 1) or (r in ['I', 'X', 'C'] and v > 3):
                return None
        if c == 'I':
            # last character in the string
            if i == len(string) - 1:
                result += 1
            elif string[i+1] == 'V':
                result += 4
                skip = i + 1
            elif string[i+1] == 'X':
                result += 9
                skip = i + 1
        elif c == 'X':
            # last character in the string
            if i == len(string) - 1:
                result += 10
            elif string[i+1] == 'L':
                result += 40
                skip = i + 1
            elif string[i+1] == 'C':
                result += 90
                skip = i + 1
        elif c == 'C':
            # last character in the string
            if i == len(string) - 1:
                result += 100
            elif string[i+1] == 'D':
                result += 400
                skip = i + 1
            elif string[i+1] == 'M':
                result += 900
                skip = i + 1
        else:
            skip = 0
            result += symbols[c]
    return result
```

However, this solution gets the wrong answer with the string `MLXVI` which should output 1066, while this code yields 1056.

Can someone please point out what's wrong with this solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting Roman Numerals to integers in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19308177/converting-roman-numerals-to-integers-in-python)

Comment: Your problem is that you do not account for `XVI == 16`

Comment: @cdarke while the question might not be exactly new, I would like to know what's wrong with my approach.

Comment: @ReblochonMasque Yes, I know it's skipping the X, and I'd like to know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That specific case would be fixed by adding an `else` statement in this block:

```
elif c == 'X':
    # last character in the string
    if i == len(string) - 1:
        result += 10
    elif string[i+1] == 'L':
        result += 40
        skip = i + 1
    elif string[i+1] == 'C':
        result += 90
        skip = i + 1
    else:
        result += 10
```

However I see that this may be happening in other places like with multiple `I`s. So `III` should be 3 but your program returns 1.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that.

Answer (score 1):

Just quickly reading, but...

`if i == skip and i != 0` wouldn't need a special case for the first characted if `skip` wasn't precisely `0`.

`if c in repetitions.items()` seems exceedingly unlikely to work; the items are tuples and `c` is a character.

`repetitions` should probably be a `collections.Counter`.

You've written special cases for a bunch of characters (`IXC`) even though the rule is consistent: lower magnitude before higher magnitude is subtracted. Among other things, these special cases have hardcoded values.

Those special cases include an implicit case where characters are ignored.