# Python cannot ignore str when input is int()

Tags: python, string, types, integer

SO I have a program where the input is in an int, but when the user enters a str, the program crashes. I want the program to ignore any str that it can't convert to an int. I tried declaring a variable that said type(input). Then, I added an if statement:

```
if (variable) == str:
  print(oops)
```

Remember I declared the input as an int. So I don't know.
Thank you.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html I hope this would help you.

Comment: You can use _try_ and catch when the input is integer, ignore it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use try-except to handle the case.

```
try:
    value = int(input())
except ValueError:
    print("Input is not an int type")
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use exceptions for this. You get a `Value Error` when you try to convert a string input to int. By enclosing it in a `try` clause here, it is telling that if a `Value Error` arises, you can ignore it. For now I've used the `pass` statement, but if there's something else you want to do if the input is a string, you can add it there.

```
try:
    x = input()
    value = int(x)
    print(value)
except ValueError:
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

In python you can call **isinstance()** on the variable passing the datatype you want to check for-

```
sent = 'your_string'
num = 24 
                                                                                      
isinstance(sent, int) # returns False
isinstance(num, int) # returns True 
isinstance(sent, str) # returns True 
isinstance(num, str) # returns False
```

Applicable with other **data types** too!

So a simple-

```
if not isinstance(str, int):
    print('Only integer values accepted')
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
if my_input.isdigit():
    int(my_input)
    # your code goes here
else:
    print('oops')
    exit() # maybe you like to exit
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like

```
input_number = input("Enter your number")
if type(eval(input_number)) == int:
    #Do stuff
else:
    print('Sorry that is an invalid input')
```

I also noticed you said

> Remeber I declared the input as an int

Python is not statically typed, so you don't have to declare a variable as a certain data type, and along with that even if you do, their type can still be changed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str.isnumeric()` to check if input is of int type or not. THis is better than using `try..except`

```
input_number = input("enter a number: ")
if input_number.isnumeric():
      input_number = int(input_number)
      # do magic
```